# Problems after overlaying AIR SDK on Flex SDK

Tags: apache-flex, sdk, air, overlay

I'm trying to overlay AIR SDK on Flex SDK on Windows machine but I am encountering issues afterwards. I tried overlaying with several official versions of both SDKs (including Apache Flex SDK) and followed the steps mentioned here: http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/how-overlay-air-sdk-flex-sdk.html

However, after pasting the AIR SDK contents in the Flex SDK folder and overwriting existing files FlashBuilder reports the following Errors when I change projects SDK:

```
"Could not resolve <mx:ViewStack> to a component implementation."
"Could not resolve <s:SWFLoader> to a component implementation."
```

I made sure that the namespace version in application descriptor is stated correctly.

What am I missing to successfully overlay both SDKs?

Comment: I highly recommend the [apache flex sdk installer](http://flex.apache.org/installer.html) for this. Just pick your SDK and AIR Version and hit start. Couldn't be easier.

Comment: Be sure select there *AIR beta* if you plan to develop for iOS7

Comment: @AlexanderFarber The beta isn't needed. AIR 13.0 has full support (fully supported since 4.0, actually) for iOS 7 and it fixed the bug where we couldn't use the iOS Simulator if XCode 5.1 was installed.

Comment: @Jan As an afterthought, you also need to make sure you download the AIR SDK for Flex, not the standard download. The standard SDK includes the  2.0 compiler which is incompatible with Flex

Comment: @Josh Janusch This is the solution, many thanks!

Comment: @T. Richter I'm using the Apache Flex SDK Installer but I do need to downgrade to earlier versions of the SDKs than I can choose in the Installer