# Some spark components missing after overlaying flex SDK with AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air, flex-spark

I want to create a flex mobile application.

I merged the contents of Adobe AIR SDK 4.0.0(build:1390) with Adobe flex SDK 4.6

Now, when I create a new flex mobile application in Flash Builder, I don't have the "ViewNavigatorApplication" or "View" spark components. Compiling gives the error:

**Could not resolve s:ViewNavigatorApplication to a component implementation.**

I noticed that **"mobilecomponents.swc"** disappears from the list of fils after merging AIR SDK with flex SDK. The "ViewNavigatorApplication" component is in this file.

I tried adding the "mobilecomponents.swc" manually, and the result was the application compiled but showd a blank white screen.

The same problem exists with Apache flex SDK 4.12.1

There are no problems when I used this overlayed flex and AIR for a pure AS3 project.

Comment: What do you mean by 'merging'? I'm not sure this is even possible, as the they are two different SDK and they have different classes working for both..

Comment: Relevant:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23262366/problems-after-overlaying-air-sdk-on-flex-sdk?rq=1

Comment: @Brian That is exactly the same question altough with different errors, wish I found it earlier.

Comment: @andrey-popov You have to merge flex and Air SDKs if you want to develop applications for mobile platforms using Air. There are many tutorials about that.

Comment: Please don't merge the AIR SDK manually, it's error prone and you won;t have an 100% perfect setup. Use the scripts in the ide directory or use the SDK installer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, problem solved!
For anyone else stuck in this situation:

Note that I was trying to install the SDK manually. I red somewhere that Apache Flex SDK installer will prevent many of this issues by automatically doing things, altough I haven't tested it myself.

Back to my situation, this link saved me: 
http://riatiger.com/blog/2013/08/overlay-adobe-air-3-8-over-flex-sdk-4-6/

The key point in the link:

> ...you should download original AIR SDK
>   without the new compiler, or you will face a bunch of weird messages
>   during project compilation.

So, you should download the AIR SDK from http://airdownload.adobe.com/air/win/download/latest/AdobeAIRSDK.zip and not the normal download page of AIR SDK. When you overlay this version of AIR SDK into flex SDK, you will notice that no files are overriden.

After doing this edit the "frameworks/airmobile-config.xml" file and remove the 2 occurrences of "{airHome}/frameworks/" to prevent a compile error.

After doing all the steps add the new flex SDK folder again in order to apply all the changes.